# xUnit - Using Context from SetFixture() In the Test Class Constructor

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, xunit, xunit.net

**EDIT:** Question revised.

I'm migrating few tests from nUnit to xUnit, and I have a question regrading the relationship between the `SetFixture()` method and the constructor. 
My tests have common setup methods. According to the xUnit manual, `[Setup]` code should now go into the constructor. Consider this example:

```
public class MyTestClass : IUseFixture<TestFixture> {

    private TestObject m_MyObject;

    public MyTestClass() {
        m_MyObject.Login()
    }

    public void SetFixture(TestFixture data) {
        m_MyObject = data.TestObject;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest() {
        Console.Writeline("My Test");
    }
```

TestObject is being initialized once on my Fixture Class. In `SetFixture()`, I'm assigning it to a local member so the test-code may use it. However, I'm also using this object during Setup. As the Constructor running before the `SetFixture()`, I'm unable to use my TestObject. What would be the solution for that issue?

Comment: One simplification of your specific code is to stop maintaining `m_MyObject` at all - simply change `SetFixture()` to read `data.Login()`. But I'm guessing you;re doing other stuff too. If you are, perhaps you could do something like `_context = data.Login()` as a way of cleaning and simplifying the logic? (Or perish the thought, you could implement `IUseFixture<TestFixture>` in a base class of your Test :D)

Comment: Edited answer to give a complete response to your updated question. Feel free to revise your question to read as if you'd asked the second form in the first instance.

Comment: Thank you Ruben. The question has been revised as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Heavily edited from rambling initial response - The first two comments (from the OP and me) are rendered obsolete by the edit.

---

You're running into a weakness in design of the xUnit v1 `IUseFixture` mechanism which applies generally to the use of Setter Method Injection [pattern documented in [the excellent Dependency Injection in .NET book]](http://manning.com/seemann)
. (See related [discussion in context of same patterns in Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns))

The ctor and `SetFixture` are indeed called once per test. In general, you should not be doing anything in the `SetFixture` other than stashing the value. The ctor of the Fixture is the place to do any Fixture-related setup (obviously that'll only happen once).

What I tend to do instead is to make my Test Classes static and then lean on [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).xUnit to avoid the `SetFixture` and/or stateful Test Classes but that may or may not be appropriate in your case.

In xUnit v2, you can add Fixtures as parameters to the Test Class constructor which would obviate the problems you're encountering. This mechanism also works especially well in conjunction with C# 6 new primary constructor mechanism (and obviously F# as everything does :)

Comment: @TomZ You're running into one of the key problems of Setter Method Injection[1]. Your [updated] question is a necessary exception to the general rule of doing stuff in the ctor as much as possible brought on by the insurmountable ordering problem you cite which is pushing you towards the Test Setup Method Warren antipattern. Having proper ctor injection support in xUnit would simplify your case (and many of mine too - though to be honest, `AutoFixture.xUnit` is my hammer for making pains like this go away). [1] Get [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann) ASAP, fantastic book

Comment: Fixtures in v2 are provided via constructor injection instead of setter injection. It's less obvious (the old interface in v1 mandated that you write the setter method), but it's also a ton more useful, because it means you get access to all the fixtures at once.

Comment: @BradWilson Thanks for confirming that (I scan the xUnit project Issue notifications and had a vague idea that was the case). Have edited my answer to read as if I was aware of this all along and have perfect recall :D

Comment: Thank you Ruben and Brad. I think that until xUnit V2 will be out to the public, I will either add some Setup code into `SetFixture()` or give a try to AutoFixture.xUnit which looks interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @Tom Z Fair enough (remember it is in NuGet, you just need to *Include Prerelease*). One thing that I should mention is that AutoFixture.xUnit does not include any intrinsic shared fixture mechanism (which is a good thing for your sanity) - my comments here suggest it a) is applicable b) can directly handle your problem; this could easily be wrong (but AutoFixture is fantastic for the maintainability and brevity of a test codebase in general and hence well worth some time)

Comment: At least at the moment, shared fixture is not something we need. So that's just fine. Thanks :)